# Own error reporting system in PHP

Tags: php

Well, I've written an application, and now I want to write something custom that will handle error reporting instead of displaying built in PHP error reporting.

I would want this software to catch PHP errors, and display the message in custom-made box, something like this is done in kohana framework...

How can I do this? I don't really want to fill my code with try-catch. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Take a look [in the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php). Also [here](https://gist.github.com/4123974).

Comment: You're looking for this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: a) there is a difference between errors and exceptions, b) try, catch is exactly the right way of dealing with exceptions, errors should not be shown but logged, for that you can use set_error_handler to implement your own way of handling errors.

Comment: Ideally a web application shouldn't raise any PHP error. If it does it is likely to become a problem sooner or later.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.phptherightway.com/#exceptions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using the [`set_error_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function.

Answer (score 5):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php

But proper way to do it is `try catch` ;)